# problem with dist-upgrade and vivid

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

i installed a fresh ubuntu 15.04 /32 on an Acer Extensa 5620.

The gui update finally ended with a "hanging" unpack of linux-headers-3.19.0-30 (3.19.0.-30.34).

So i decided to start again with a fresh install. I only worked in a terminal (Alt+Ctrl+F1) and repeated update/upgrade until only the dist-upgrade was left.

Unfortunately again the system hangs at "Extracting of linux-headers-3.19 ....(as above).

The system itself is usable and i can even go into the desktop. But whatever i try - i am unable to finish the dist-upgrade.

Any help?

Comment: How long did you wait? The installation of the headers can take a while, especially if there are several [DKMS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS) modules to be build.

Comment: Yes - that was the Problem. I let the Computer run for more than 1 hour and finally it finished. So maybe it would be helpfull to give some more progress Information for long lasting tasks?

Comment: Well, patience is a virtue :-) But I agree, some indicator would be nice. Of course there is good old `top` you can run in another terminal and see if processes are still active. Although the solution is very simple, the question deserves an answer. Post one and accept it yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just takes some time to finish the updsates. Allthough no activity can be senn and even looking with top did not really answer my question. After waiting more than one hour the update finished.

So just be patient...